# How to refactor common methods of sets of int and string into a common base?

Tags: go, generics, set

Consider the following program that defines two types `IntSet` and `StringSet` for sets containing `int`s and `string`s respectively.

The `Add()`, `AddRange()`, `Contains()`, `ContainsAny`, and `Length()` of these types are basically the same (only the argument types differ).

I could define standalone functions `Add()`, `AddRange()`, ... without method receivers and with `interface{}` argument for `IntSet` or `StringSet`, but I would like these methods to stay coupled with the sets.

If I use [composition](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/inheritance-in-golang/), then the base struct can't access the `map[...]bool` of the child struct.

What's the proper way of refactoring the five methods above to remove code duplication?

Program:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "sort"
    "strconv"
    "strings"
)


type IntSet map[int]bool
type StringSet map[string]bool

func NewStringSet(vs []string) StringSet {
    ss := StringSet{}
    for _, v := range vs {
        ss.Add(v)
    }
    return ss
}

func (ss StringSet) Add(v string) bool {
    _, found := ss[v]
    ss[v] = true
    return !found
}

func (ss StringSet) AddRange(vs []string) {
    for _, v := range vs {
        ss[v] = true
    }
}

func (ss StringSet) Contains(v string) bool {
    _, found := ss[v]
    return found
}

func (ss StringSet) ContainsAny(vs []string) bool {
    for _, v := range vs {
        if _, found := ss[v]; found {
            return true
        }
    }
    return false
}

func (ss StringSet) Length() int {
    return len(ss)
}

func (ss StringSet) Stringify() string {
    vs := make([]string, len(ss))
    i := 0
    for v := range ss {
        vs[i] = v
        i++
    }
    return strings.Join(vs, ",")
}

func NewIntSet(vs []int) IntSet {
    is := IntSet{}
    for _, v := range vs {
        is.Add(v)
    }
    return is
}

func (is IntSet) Add(v int) bool {
    _, found := is[v]
    is[v] = true
    return !found
}

func (is IntSet) AddRange(vs []int) {
    for _, v := range vs {
        is[v] = true
    }
}

func (is IntSet) Contains(v int) bool {
    _, found := is[v]
    return found
}

func (is IntSet) ContainsAny(vs []int) bool {
    for _, v := range vs {
        if _, found := is[v]; found {
            return true
        }
    }
    return false
}

func (is IntSet) Length() int {
    return len(is)
}

func (is IntSet) Stringify() string {
    vs := make([]int, 0)
    for v := range is {
        vs = append(vs, v)
    }
    sort.Ints(vs)
    ws := make([]string, 0)
    for v := range vs {
        s := strconv.Itoa(v)
        ws = append(ws, s)
    }
    return strings.Join(ws, ",")
}
```

Comment: Use `interface{}` or wait for generics to land, should be in Go 1.18 which will be released in the first half of next year.

Comment: Wait for Go 1.18 which brings parametric polymorphism to the table.

Comment: @mkopriva So you recommend using standalone functions with `interface{}` argument and type switch?

Comment: @Shuzheng no I do not recommend it, but interfaces are the only way to make generic code in Go at the moment. If you want my recommendation then here it is: keep the duplicate code, it's fine, really, not everything has to be dry, the stdlib also has a bunch of duplicate code and nobody complains.

Comment: Expanding on mkopriva's last comment: Your code should be WET, not DRY.

Answer (score 1):

Just keep the duplicate code. Five methods are a non-issue in terms of maintenance overhead.

Anyway here's an obligatory example with generics, which also works on the [Go2 playground](https://go2goplay.golang.org/p/rVd91WQAPZj):

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
)

type Set[T comparable] map[T]bool

func NewSet[T comparable](vs []T) Set[T] {
    ss := Set[T]{}
    for _, v := range vs {
        ss.Add(v)
    }
    return ss
}

func (s Set[T]) Add(v T) bool {
    _, found := s[v]
    s[v] = true
    return !found
}

func (s Set[T]) AddRange(vs []T) {
    for _, v := range vs {
        s[v] = true
    }
}

func (s Set[T]) Contains(v T) bool {
    _, found := s[v]
    return found
}

func (s Set[T]) ContainsAny(vs []T) bool {
    for _, v := range vs {
        if _, found := s[v]; found {
            return true
        }
    }
    return false
}

func (s Set[T]) Length() int {
    return len(s)
}

func (s Set[T]) Stringify() string {
    vs := make([]interface{}, len(s))
    i := 0
    for v := range s {
        vs[i] = v
        i++
    }
    return fmt.Sprintf("%v", vs)
}

func main() {
    sset := NewSet([]string{"foo", "bar"})
    sset.Add("baz")
    fmt.Println(sset.Stringify()) // [foo bar baz]

    iset := NewSet([]int{12, 13, 14})
    iset.Add(20)
    fmt.Println(iset.Stringify()) // [12 13 14 20]
}
```

In particular:

- the constraint used in `Set`'s type parameter must be `comparable`, as map keys must support comparison operators (`==`, `!=`)
- the type param must be repeated explicitly in all receivers, but the constraint need not be repeated. So you have `func (s Set[T]) ...` in all methods
- the implementation of `Stringify()` is pesky because the type parameter `T comparable` doesn't support string operations. It's just a `comparable`. So above I naively use `[]interface{}` and `fmt.Sprintf`, which just does the job